# Limit of complex sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I am unsure as what to do with the problem:

Prove that the sequence $ z_n $ converges and find its limit.

$ z_n = \frac {n+i}{1-in}  $

If $z_n$ is convergent that means that the real part and the imaginary part is convergent, which means:

$ z_n = x_n+iy_n → z = x+iy ⇔ x_n →x, y_n→y $

So how do I split the sequence $z_n$ up into the real part and the imaginary part? (I guess that is what I am suppose to do or is there a simpler method?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

You can do this with multiplying numerator and denominator in $1+in$. Then
$$\dfrac{n+i}{1-in}\times\dfrac{1+in}{1+in}$$
and complete the solution.

Comment: So by multiplying the numerator and the denominator with 1+in I get: $ \frac{n+in^2+i-n}{1+n^2} = \frac{i(n^2+1)}{1+n^2} = i $ which means that the real part is 0 - converges to 0 - and the imaginary part is 1, which means that it converges to 1?

Comment: Yes. So $z_n\to i$.

Answer (score 0):

There is: 
$$\frac{n+i}{1-in} = \frac{n+i}{1-in}\cdot \frac{1+in}{1+in} = \frac{i(n^2+1)}{1+n^2} = i.$$